# Setting UILabel margins

Tags: ios, swift, autolayout, uilabel

On a `UILabel` variable, in order to set some margin to my taste on the 4 sides, between the text and the border of the `UILabel` view. I have subclassed `UILabel` and overwrote the `intrinsicContentSize()` function, like this:

```
override func intrinsicContentSize() -> CGSize {
    var resultSize = super.intrinsicContentSize()
    resultSize.width += 20.0
    resultSize.height += 10.0
    return resultSize
}
```

I get exactly the result I want for the height, but for the width nothing happens.
Can anyone see why?

Comment: If this gets called more than once on an instance, you'll see its intrinsic size grow and grow...

Comment: You may be right, but I am not sure I see why, because I am using the value returned by super each time and this should always be the same. Unless the value returned by super changes also? Am I wrong?
Anyway I am willing to use another way if I can get the margins the way I want.

Comment: @Michel Your code works well for me, but keep in mind that text in the label is still aligned to left edge no matter how much you increase frame.

Comment: Well, I will find another way to get the result I want then. I must say I do not quite understand what intrinsicContentSize() is supposed to do though.
The width parameter seems meaningless.